# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Pass phrase must be a buffer

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, passport.js

This is my code but I get the message :  UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection (rejection id: 2): TypeError: Pass phrase must be a buffer
whenever I type on my passport input and use the post request under "/registrar" where I create my new User, can't seem to find the reason why it would throw the error, tried with hardcoded data instead of the req.body.etc. but still got the same error. Help!

```
var express               = require("express"),

mongoose              = require("mongoose"),
passport              = require("passport"),
bodyParser            = require("body-parser"),
User                  = require("./models/user"),
LocalStrategy         = require("passport-local"),
passportLocalMongoose = require("passport-local-mongoose");


mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/ommbc_app");
var app = express();
// app.set("view engine", "ejs");
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/assets/css'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname + '/views/assets/js'));
app.use(express.static(__dirname+'/views/assets'));
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}));
app.use(require("express-session")({
    secret: "OMMBC PRRO",
    resave: false,
    saveUninitialized: false
}));

app.use(passport.initialize());
app.use(passport.session());

passport.use(new LocalStrategy(User.authenticate()));
passport.serializeUser(User.serializeUser());
passport.deserializeUser(User.deserializeUser());


///ROUTES
app.get("/", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/login.html")
});

app.get("/login", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/login.html")
});

app.get("/problemas",isLoggedIn, function(req,res){
    res.render("/");
});

//AUTH ROUTES
app.get("/registrar", function(req,res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+'/views/signup.html');
});

//handling user sign up
app.post("/registrar",function(req,res){
    // console.log(req.body.username);
    // console.log(req.body.password);
    // req.body.username
    // req.body.password
    User.register(new User(
        {
            username: req.body.username,
            password: req.body.password
        }),function(err,user){
        if(err){
            console.log('HEllo');
            console.log(err);
            return res.sendFile("/login");
        }
        // else{
        //     console.log("LOGGEDIN ");
        //     passport.authenticate("local")(req,res,function(){
        //         res.redirect("/problemas");
        //     });
        // }
    }
    );
});

//LOGIN ROUTES
// app.get("/login", function(req,res){
//     res.sendFile(__dirname+"/views/login")
// });

app.post("/login",passport.authenticate("local",{
    successRedirect: "/problemas",
    failureRedirect: "/login"
}) ,function(req,res){
});

app.listen(process.env.PORT, process.env.IP, function(){
    console.log("Server Started...");
});

//MIDDLEWARE
app.get("/logout",function(req,res){
    req.logout();
    res.redirect("/")
});


function isLoggedIn(req,res,next){
    if(req.isAuthenticated()){
        return next();
    }
    else{
        res.redirect("/login");
    }
}
```

Comment: `User` model code would be helpful to understand the problem with `User` schema

Answer (score 0):

Kinda found the problem since I can send the data of User to the database, but my main issue is im trying to send the password without hashing , cause in the future is supposed to be an API instead of a db.

var mongoose = require("mongoose"); var passportLocalMongoose =          require("passport-local-mongoose"); var UserSchema = new mongoose.Schema({ nombre: String, password: String, }); UserSchema.plugin(passportLocalMongoose); module.exports = mongoose.model("User", UserSchema);